# problem on permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In $S_{10}$, can someone explain why there is no permutation $a$ such that $a(1,2,3)a^{-1} = (1,3)(5,7,8)$?

Comment: Because they are of different signs

Comment: There is even a stronger reason: the operation $aba^{-1}$ is only a "relabelling" of the elements of $b$, hence it has the same cycle structure as $b$. Not true here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three explanations of this fact :

- First, the order of $a(1,2,3)a^{-1}$ is the order of $(1,2,3)$ which is $3$, whereas the order of $(1,3)(5,7,8)$ is $6$.
- Second, the signature $\epsilon$. We have that :

$$\epsilon(a(1,2,3)a^{-1})=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(1,2,3)\epsilon(a)^{-1}=\epsilon(1,2,3)=1 $$

Whereas :

$$\epsilon((1,3)(5,7,8))=\epsilon(1,3)\epsilon(5,7,8)=-1\times 1=-1 $$

- Last but not least, from an easy and very usefull lemma :

$$a(1,2,3)a^{-1}=(a(1),a(2),a(3)) $$

Thus if you had :

$$(a(1),a(2),a(3))=a(1,2,3)a^{-1}=(1,3)(5,7,8) $$

You would contradict the unicity of disjoint support cycles decomposition.